# Too many click handlers being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following function to dynamically populate a div with some text and a button using the array *messages*:

```
var populateMessages = function(messages){
    for (var index in messages){
        (function(){
            var id = index;
            $("#messages").append(messages[index]["title"])
            $("#messages").append("<button>Open</button><br/>").click(function(){console.log(message["id"])})
        }())
    }
};
```

This code correctly populates the div with the text and the button. The problem is that if I click on ANY of the buttons, the click handlers for ALL of them fire. So with two buttons, it should log "0" if I click on the first one and "1" if I click on the second. Instead, if I click on either, it logs "0 1"

I'm not super up on Javascript so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Would you mind creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) containing minimum code that can reproduce the problem? It would be easier for people to test and demonstrate the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of

```
$("#messages").append("<button>Open</button><br/>")
```

is `#messages`, not the button that was added. So each time through the loop you're adding another click handler to `#messages`, not the button.

Try:

```
$.each(messages, function(index, message) {
    $("#messages").append(message.title);
    $("<button>Open</button>").click(function() {
        console.log(message.id);
    }).appendTo("#messages");
    $("#messages").append("<br/>");
});
```

Comment: Yes, this was the solution I just realized myself.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku: Recommend you up/vote accept someone else's answer as they put the effort into helping you. Also recommend delete your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#messages").append("<button>Open</button><br/>")
```

Returns `#messages` not `button` so you are setting the click event to `#message`.

Try this:

```
$("#messages").append("<button>Open</button><br/>").find("button:last").click(/blabla/)
```

Comment: Or `$("<button>Open</button><br/>").appendTo('#messages').click(...)`.